# Finding and removing an object from arraylist while not knowing the object's variables

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to `Java` and i've been bashing my head over the wall to solve this problem.  Anyway below is a class that creates a Person and below that, is a class that creates a `Phonebook` using an `ArrayList` of type Person. I want to write the remove function (in order to remove a `Person` from the list) but my problem is that since i only get the name of the person i can't use the Indexof function (cause it requires object) to get at what position lies the name.

This is my first time using an `ArrayList` to store an Object so i'm not even sure 
 how my results would appear. I'm guessing that if the position of the name (in my list) is 10 then 11 would be the phone and 12 would be the address. Am i correct?

```
public class Person
    {
       private String name;
       private String phone;
       private String address;

public Person (String n, String p, String a)
{
     this.name = n;
     this.phone = p;
     this.address = a;
}

public void setPhone(String newPhone)
{
   this.phone = newPhone;
}

public String getName()
{
     return this.name;
}

public String getPhone()
{
      return this.phone;
}

public String getAddress()
{
      return this.address;
}



public String print()
{
      return "Name is : " + this.name + "\nPhone is : " + this.phone + "\nAddress is : " + this.address;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.*;

public class phoneBook
{
            Scanner in = new Scanner ( System.in );
            private ArrayList <Person> persons = new ArrayList <Person>();
            private int i;
            private boolean flag;


        public void addPerson(Person p)
        {
            persons.add(p);
        }

        public void listPersons () 
        {
            System.out.println(persons);
        }

        public void lookUp (String theName) 
        {
            flag = persons.contains(theName);
            if ( flag == true )
            {
                System.out.println("That name exists!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("That name does not exist!");
            }
        }

        public void remove (String theName) 
        {

        }
```

Edit: I'm planning to use the Scanner in another function. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of if do you want to get the object of that array, but each object is indexed  to that array (with full attributes), now you can remove it by using the following code,

```
public String removePerson(ArrayList<Person> arrayList,String name)
{
 for(Person currentPerson:arrayList)
 {
     if(currentPerson.getName().equals(name))
     {
         arrayList.remove(currentPerson);
         return "Removed successfully"
     }
 }
 return "No record found for that person";
}
```

just pass the arrayList and the name of that person to this method

Comment: So that would remove every element of the Object meaning his phone and his address would be deleted aswell.

Comment: well, if you have passed the arrayList and person name, it will remove the Object with all its attributes,if do you want to remove it by phoneNumber pass this number instead of name and change currentPeroson.getName()
to currentPerson.getPhoneNumber()

Comment: make it as accepted answer so that other people can see this answer once they see this question

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in the Person class. This way you will define when two objects of this type will be considered equal. Then you can use `list.contains(yourObject)` to determine if that object is equal to any object in your list, this based on your `equals()` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
   public void remove (String theName,ArrayList<Person> persons)   {

       for (int i = 0; i < persons.size();++i) {

           if(persons[i].getName().equals(theName)) {

              persons.remove(i);
           }
      }   
   }
```

Best regards, Nazar

Comment: Yes that helps! Thanks!